# MYSQL associative count

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm trying to count some comments, and when I display the companies and I want next to each company to display a comments count, something like on a blog, when you display the total count of comments on a posts list.

My Query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM `company_admin_notes`
WHERE company_id IN(49152,49408,49155) GROUP by company_id;
```

And it gives me something like this:
[image]

So I need something like

```
 total | company_id
 5     | 49152
 4     | 4908
```

So I know which count goes to which company, or if you guys have any other ideas how can I achieve something like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total, company_id FROM `company_admin_notes`WHERE company_id IN(49152,49408,49155) GROUP by company_id;
```

Comment: Looks wrong to me, you have `COUNT(*), company_id as total` but it should be `COUNT(*) as total, company_id` ... right?

Comment: Wow, great! I will accept it asap! Thank you. Maybe if you can also add a comment on what is different

Comment: @naththedeveloper Oops, thanks for pointing that out!! Fixed now

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total,company_id FROM `company_admin_notes`
WHERE company_id IN(49152,49408,49155) GROUP by company_id
HAVING COUNT(*)>0;
```